# Bluetooth audio stops outputting

Tags: sound, bluetooth

Running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. I have just installed an Intel AX200 Wifi card with a bluetooth chip built-in. For the most part, bluetooth has worked on Ubuntu. However, audio has been stopping mid playback. I have to go into the sound settings and switch from Bluetooth to Line-in and back again to get sound output working.

Other times, I go into the audio settings and the bluetooth audio channel isn't even an option, despite being on, and connected and visible to the PC. What could be causing the intermittent bluetooth audio?

I never installed any drivers as far as I am aware, I simply plugged in the card and bluetooth became available in Ubuntu settings.

I have done some research and the only thing to come up is PulseAudio, an audio server, which is something I have not installed afaik.

Comment: Just had the audio drop out again for no reason, and now I cannot get it to come back despite turning the headphones off and on. Restarting is the only way to fix it so far, but I don't want to have to restart my PC all the time because something basic that should work fine isn't.